# Exporting data frames faster than write.csv()

Tags: r, export

I need some help.

I have a script in R that is preforming tasks on a data frame that is either going to be 20148000, 4029600 or 50370000 rows. I have a machine that can handle preforming the tasks at these sizes in a couple minutes depending on the size of I select. However, I need to loop this 3002, 1501 or 1201 time respectively. That total run time is fine.

The problem I am having is at the end of every loop I need to export this huge data frame. When I use a `write.csv()` in R, it turns my run time for one iteration from 2 minutes to 15.5 minutes. Is there something more efficient than `write.csv()`??

Comment: Wouldn't it be preferable to use a database?

Comment: Can R import and export from a database?

Comment: Yes.  See the `DBI` package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/index.html  -or- the `RODBC` package http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html for starters

Comment: or `RPostgreSQL` or `RMySQL` or `RSQLite` or...

Comment: Thank you, Is there a software that is good to use to make the database with?